# loop multidimensional array with repeated item

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$pplinfo  = array(

        array("name" => "alan",
              "sex" => "male",
              "favourite" => "white","black","pink" 
        ),
        array(  "name" => "eric",
                "sex" => "male",
                "favourite" => "red","grey","navy","white","purple","chocolate" 
        ),
);
```

How to get result with foreach loop function to become as below,

alan is a male like white

alan is a male like black

alan is a male like pink

eric is a male like red

eric is a male like grey

eric is a male like navy

eric is a male like white

eric is a male like purple

eric is a male like chocolate

Comment: Have you tried to write some code to do this?

Comment: First things first, I believe that "favourite" should be an array too.

Comment: @matiit probably `favourite` value generate error.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Hope `favourite` is also array. using it you can achieve your result like below:

```
$pplinfo  = array(

  array(
          "name" => "alan",
          "sex" => "male",
          "favourite" => array("white","black","pink")

  ),
  array(
          "name" => "eric",
          "sex" => "male",
          "favourite" => array("red","grey","navy","white","purple","chocolate")

  ),
);

foreach ($pplinfo as $key => $value) {
  $favourites = $value['favourite'];
  foreach ($favourites as $favourite) {    
    echo $value['name']." is a ".$value['sex']." like ".$favourite;
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: If we keep "Doing it all for them" then they will just keep coming back again and again having made no attempt to "Do something for themselves"

Comment: Ya @RiggsFolly You are right. I will keep in mind this next time. Thanks

Comment: @B.Desai thanks for your help! your solution works perfectly!